How to stop getting logged out every time I migrate:fresh in Laravel
In Laravel 11, every time I run migrate:fresh while developing, I am logged out of the session
So I have to re-login 100 times
Is there a way to keep me logged in even after running migrate:fresh?
I've tried removing the AuthenticateSession middleware, which did not help
I also tried hardcoding a remember_token in my user factory, which did not help

Most probably you are using sessions table in your DB. When you migrate:fresh it deletes that session table.
Try to use file in your .env SESSION_DRIVER
You can find out more in the docs:
https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/session#configuration

Heads up! It won't work if you're using a UUID or ULID for the user_id. In other words, make sure that the user_id before running the migration matches the user_id after migrating and creating the user.
